Azure Active Directory App service Principal create new client secret
I have an Azure Active Directory App service Principal's client secret will expired soon.
Can I just create a new client secret without rotating the existing one and waiting for the old one to expire? Will it automatically use the new client secret?
I'm using Azure Active Directory App service Principal for Azure DevOps Docker service connection. It didn't require me to enter client secret. Approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops#create-an-application-service-principal
Docker service connection pic


Yes, you can create new client secret for your registered application in Azure Entra ID without waiting for existing one to expire.

@PratikJadhav Thanks for answering. I don't have to take any further action, and once the old client secret expires, the ACR service connection will use the new one, right?

No, once the old client secret get expired, you need to update it to use the new client secret.


Will it automatically use the new client secret

No, it will not use the new secret automatically.
To resolve this issue, you can try the following workarounds:

Delete the expired secret and create a new one. Make some changes to your service connection, for example, add or edit the Description filed. Then click the Save button. It may take some time to refresh the token.


Create a new Container Registry service connection and use workload identity federation as the authentication type.
Workload identity federation enables you to use short-lived tokens for authenticating to Azure and remove the limit of the service principle's secret. So that you don't need to create a new service connection when the secret expires again.

See more info about workload identity federation from Workload identity federation and 
September 11th, 2023
Introduction to Azure DevOps Workload identity federation.



Thanks! The second way is better and works for me.
